# for loop over list break and continue

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, break

To specify the problem correctly :i apologize for the confusion 
Having doubts with breaking early from loop .
I have folders - 1995,1996 to 2014 . Each folder has xml files. In some xml files the entry - MaxAmdLetterDate is None. 
I want to proceed to the next file in the folder, instead right now with break , the program execution goes to the next folder and skips all files in that folder when it encounters a break 
This is the code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
for yrcnt in range(1995,2015):
    old= old="./old/"+ str(yrcnt)
    for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(old): #folder name in which subfolder>files are present
        print files
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(".xml") == True:
                fl=filename
                print fl
                print "-----Reading current file -------"  + str(fl)
                flnm=str(dirpath)+"/"+str(filename)
                tree1 = ET.parse(flnm)                        #db on system
                root1 = tree1.getroot()
                for ch1 in root1.findall('Award'):
                    aid1 = ch1.find('AwardID').text
                    maxdate1=ch1.find('MaxAmdLetterDate').text
                    print "Max amd date : "+str(maxdate1)
            if maxdate1==None:
                break
```

Help is appreciated .

ORIGINAL POST:
My for loop gets an early exit on encountering a break . Any remedies ?

```
files=[1,2,3,4,5]
for filename in files:
  print filename
  if filename==3:
     break
```

o/p:

```
  1
  2
  3
```

expected O/p

```
  1
  2
  4
  5
```

Thanks !

EDIT: With some comments such as this is expected function of break . Let me elucidate: I want the function to be similar to a range(0,5) , Iam using this as a part of nested loop where I want the loop to go on , and not exit out due to one file .

Comment: what are you expect to get?

Comment: Please show expected input and output. Your question doesn't really make sense. This is like asking "my function returns upon reaching the return statement, how do I fix this?"

Comment: That's what break statements *do by definition...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way `break` works. If you want to iterate over the whole list, simply remove the `break` (or if you want to do something with the value, use `pass` as a placeholder).

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for value in values:
    if value == 3:
        pass
    print(value)
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

If you just want to a skip a value, use `continue` keyword.

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for value in values:
    if value == 3:
        continue
    print(value)
```

Output:

```
1
2
4
5
```

Answer (score 1):

`Break` automatically exits out of your loop. If you do not want to print the filename when it is 3, use an `if` statement like this:

```
files=[1,2,3,4,5]
for filename in files:
  if filename!=3:
     print filename
```

This is the result:

```
1
2
4
5
```