# How "break" in iterative Python loop works

Tags: python, loops, iteration, break

Newbie here, so bear with me...I've tried researching this on Python.org and Google, it's still not clear to me what's happening here.

**The basic questions are:**

1. What is break doing in the following iterative loops?
2. Why do both if statements work, even though one uses the "`>=`" and the other uses "`<=`" ?
3. Why are the number of items parsed in the feed different? The first has 5 items it parses, the second parses 6 items.

**Script # 1:**

```
Import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse('http://smrss.neulion.com/u/nhl/mrss/sights-and-sounds/vod.xml')

for index, item in enumerate(d.entries):
    if index >= 5:
        break
    print item.title
```

**Script # 1 output:**

> Sights and Sounds: Flames vs. Ducks - Game 2
>
> Sights and Sounds: Wild vs. Blackhawks - Game 2
>
> Mic'd Up: Kucherov nets his third goal
>
> Mic'd Up: Kucherov nets his second goal
>
> Sights and Sounds: Capitals vs. Rangers - Game 2

**script # 2:**

```
Import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse('http://smrss.neulion.com/u/nhl/mrss/sights-and-sounds/vod.xml')

for index, item in enumerate(d.entries):
    if index <= 5:
        print item.title
```

**Script # 2 output:**

> Sights and Sounds: Flames vs. Ducks - Game 2
>
> Sights and Sounds: Wild vs. Blackhawks - Game 2
>
> Mic'd Up: Kucherov nets his second goal
>
> Mic'd Up: Kucherov nets his second goal
>
> Sights and Sounds: Capitals vs. Rangers - Game 2
>
> The best Sights and Sounds from Round 1

Comment: possible duplicate of [for loop over list break and continue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30017958/for-loop-over-list-break-and-continue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a loop that iterates over the entries available in the document `http://smrss.neulion.com/u/nhl/mrss/sights-and-sounds/vod.xml`:

```
for index, item in enumerate(d.entries):
```

The `enumerate()` call here transforms a list like `['alice', 'bob', 'frank']` into a list of tuples where each tuple contains the index of the corresponding item in the list, e.g., `[(0, 'alice'), (1, 'bob'), (2, 'frank')]`.

In the loop, `index` gets the value of the index and `item` is assigned the corresponding item from `d.entries`.  The first loop body looks like this:

```
if index >= 5:
    break
print item.title
```

This says, "if the index is greather than or equal to 5, exit the loop".  So this will print the title of items with index of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5, and then exit the loop (i.e., it prints the first six entries).

The second loop body looks like this:

```
if index <= 5:
    print item.title
```

This says, "if the index is less than or equal to five, print the item's title".  This will *also* print the first six entries, but *the loop will continue to iterate over all remaining entries without printing them*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation! Regarding the second loop body, doesn't this actually print out the first 6 entries?

Comment: @DingleJohnson: Yes, you're right. It will print the list values with the indexes from 0 to 5 with a total of 6.

Comment: Yeah, I totally ignored the `=` in `<=`.  Fixed.